# Laying out a hierarchy of views

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, autoresizingmask

So far in my iOS project, I've done almost everything in code. I've laid out my views by setting frames manually in the `layoutSubviews` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` methods. However, this is a very manual way and I'm considering other methods, such as AutoLayout...my problem is that I'm inexperienced with AutoLayout (and other methods such as using Auto-resizing masks).

My problem with manually laying out is as follows:

Let's say I'm adding subviews to a view controller's view. Now let's say I'm adding subviews to those subviews, etc. My problem is that many of those child views are dynamically-sized, i.e. their size depends on data from a server.

So now it comes time to layout the child views' frames from the parent view - since parent views define the frame of their child views before the child views layout. But while the child views have been instantiated, they haven't been laid out, so they haven't set their frames, so I don't know how large they will be.

This has been **extremely** annoying. My solution to this problem has been to implement a method for these child views which returns how large they will be based on their data. This is extraneous, time consuming and tedious.

My question is - will switching to AutoLayout (or Auto-resizing masks) make these problems go away? Will they lend themselves to the same amount of re-usability that setting frames manually does? Am I just doing something wrong in general?

Comment: AutoLayout (or Auto-resizing masks) are good for setting up how frames relate with the end of the screen or in case of AutoLayout also to another frame. I might be wrong but I don't think any of those will give you dynamic content based resize. You can use UITableView or UICollectionView and provide height for cells while it takes care of the scrolling and virtualization. You could also implement your own custom layout system with `measure` and `layout` methods or go for custom UICollectionView layout.

Comment: I come from an HTML/CSS background where you can just put div on top of div on top of div and one will go right after the other. I feel like it is just easier to work with than all this manual labor involved with creating iOS views...but then again I guess there is a LOT more HTML in the world than objective-c.

Comment: And if AutoLayout helps with how frames relate to one another...maybe it would solve some of my problems...so if I set a scrollview's frame to be at the bottom of a uiview's frame, then whenever I expand that uiview, the scrollview would expand automatically right? Would save me at least some layout...if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: From what I remember UIScrollView frame should stay the same but as you add elements you need to update `contentSize`. For example adding subview with frame y = 0, height = 100 and the next at y = 110, height = 50 you would have to set contentSize.height = 160 and the scroll view frame might be with height = 100 (you will see scroll) or for example 200 and you see no scroll

Comment: You're correct, and unfortunately this makes it hard to "bind" the scroll view's bottom to another view's bottom with something like auto layout.